# Link and scroll to section

Tags: javascript, html

Before anyone comments stating that this has been asked many times, yes, it has, however none of the solutions I have found work for what I need.

I have navigation like so:

```
link 1 (/link1/)
- sub link 1 (/link1/#sublink1)
- sub link 2 (/link1/#sublink2)

link 2
- sub link 1 (/link2/#sublink1)
- sub link 2 (/link2/#sublink2)
```

The top level links link to other pages on the website, and the sub level links are anchors to sections within that page. I am trying to get smooth scrolling to a section both when a sublink is clicked on a page the user is on, and also when a sublink of another page is clicked (browser should load that other page and THEN scroll down). Currently I can only get one or the other working - not both.

**Method 1** (works when a sublink on another page is clicked - browser loads another page then scrolls down, but doesnt work on sublinks of a page the user is already on)

```
jQuery('body, html').animate({
   scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top
}, 1300)
```

**Method 2** (the complete opposite of method 1)
// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior

```
if (this.hash !== "") {

        // Store hash
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 1300, function(){

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    } // End if
```

I basically somehow need to combine these two methods so that smooth scrolling works in all cases but am at a loss! Any ideas?

Comment: Since browsers natively scroll when a hash/anchor is matched in the document, use hashes that do not directly match that target anchor. Actual anchor being `sublink` and use `#scroll-to-sublink` for the actual links that you handle. ***Pros:** work in both of your scenarios* / ***Cons:** will not work for non-js users/browsers*.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Not sure I follow - how can the anchors and the links be different and still work?

Comment: You get the hash and remove the `scroll-to` prefix and use the result for the actual finding of the element and scrolling-to.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I now have what you mention in place, however I still have the same issue of the code working for one method, but not the other. This is because on one method I need to get the link click event, however the other is on page load and I am currently unsure how to combine the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this

```js
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) { // this handles links in same page
  scrollToAnchor(800); 
}).on('load', function(e){
  scrollToAnchor(1300); // this handles links to different pages
});

// here we handle animating to already active hash
// as the hashchange will not be triggered
$('a[href$="-st"]').on('click', function(e){
  var hash = this.hash; // not supported everywhere
  if (hash === window.location.hash){
    scrollToAnchor(800);
  }
});

function scrollToAnchor(duration) {
  var hash = window.location.hash,
    cleanhash = hash.replace(/-st$/, '');

  if (hash && (hash !== cleanhash)) { // it was indeed ending in -st
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(cleanhash).offset().top
    }, duration);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this - much better than what I had! I just had a bit of a tight deadline so needed something quick (and dirty).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to do something like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
    var cleanHash = hash.replace("-st", "");
    var currPath = window.location.pathname;

   if (hash !== null && hash !== '')
        jQuery('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(cleanHash).offset().top
        }, 1300);

    $("a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkPath = $(this)[0].pathname;
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var linkHash = href.substr(href.indexOf("#"));
        var cleanLinkHash = linkHash.replace("-st", "");

        if(linkPath !== currPath){
            window.location.href = href;
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(cleanLinkHash).offset().top
            }, 800, function(){
                window.location.hash = cleanLinkHash;
            });
        }
    });
```

It ain't pretty and needs refinement, but it works for my case. The important part being to check if the path of the link is equal to the current page and then use the different methods of scrolling accordingly.

Comment: added an answer with a somewhat cleaner version (*i think*).